# Who is this Justice League character featured in JL8?

Tags: dc, character-identification, justice-league, webcomics, jl8

JL8 (formerly Little League) is a webcomic based around the Justice League characters as young children in school.

In http://jl8comic.tumblr.com/post/26169864237/ who is the girl in the last panel meant to be?  I recognize the rest of the characters so far, but this character hasn't been in any of the Justice League comics I have read so far (mainly Grant Morrison's run).

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**That is Karen Star, also known as [Power Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Girl).** The reason you don't know her, especially if you are reading Grant Morrison's Justice League, is she is NOT a member of the JLA.

[image]

She is a Kryptonian from a parallel universe (the [Pre-Crisis Earth 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-Two), to be precise) and she would be an analog of [Supergirl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl) from the mainstream DC Universe. She is gifted with all of the powers of mainstream Kryptonians with a bit of an anger management issue from time to time.